# Changing number size on Color Map in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm sure this is probably easy and a simple fix, but I was having a lot of trouble with changing the number sizes on the colormap. Below is the code I have

```
  from matplotlib import cm
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  from matplotlib.colors import Normalize

  cmap = cm.get_cmap('plasma')
  fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25,25))
  norm = Normalize(vmin=min(dz), vmax=max(dz))
  colors = cmap(norm(dz))
  sc = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap,norm=norm)
  sc.set_array([])
  plt.colorbar(sc)
```

I am aware on how to change them for the graph with

```
  plt.xticks(size=20)
  plt.yticks(size=20)
```

But just not for the colormap. If anyone can help I would appreciate it.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `labelsize` argument of the `tick_params` method of the Axes associated to the colorbar. Have a look at the following example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import default_rng

data = default_rng(0).random((25, 100))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ctrf = ax.contourf(data)
cbar = fig.colorbar(ctrf)
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=16)
plt.show()
```

[image]